# Oracle query using Window function

Tags: oracle, function, window

Please suppose I have an Oracle table called MYDATA, with the following content:

```
NAME,    D1,         D2
A,       01/01/2010, 02/03/2010
B,       03/03/2010, 20/03/2010
C,       10/03/2010, 20/09/2010
D,       10/12/2010, 31/12/2010


Insert into MYDATA
   (NAME, D1, D2)
 Values
   ('A', TO_DATE('01/01/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/02/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into MYDATA
   (NAME, D1, D2)
 Values
   ('B', TO_DATE('03/03/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/20/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into MYDATA
   (NAME, D1, D2)
 Values
   ('C', TO_DATE('03/10/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('09/20/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into MYDATA
   (NAME, D1, D2)
 Values
   ('D', TO_DATE('12/10/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/31/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

I would like to mark with 'S' the records which have overlapping intervals: in this case, record B and record C overlap.

I have written the following Oracle query:

```
  SELECT   name, D1, D2, WMSYS.WM_CONCAT (OVERLAPPING)
    FROM   (SELECT   T1.name, T1.D1, T1.D2, NULL OVERLAPPING
              FROM   MYDATA T1, MYDATA T2
             WHERE   NOT ( (T1.D1, T1.D2) OVERLAPS (T2.D1, T2.D2))
                     AND T1.NAME <> T2.NAME
            UNION
            SELECT   T1.name, T1.D1, T1.D2, 'S'
              FROM   MYDATA T1, MYDATA T2
             WHERE   ( (T1.D1, T1.D2) OVERLAPS (T2.D1, T2.D2))
                     AND T1.NAME <> T2.NAME)
GROUP BY   NAME, D1, D2;
```

The result is:

```
NAME, D1,         D2,         WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(OVERLAPPING)
A,    01/01/2010, 02/03/2010, NULL
B,    03/03/2010, 20/03/2010, S
C,    10/03/2010, 20/09/2010, S
D,    10/12/2010, 31/12/2010, NULL
```

As you can see, the table MYDATA joins itself, marking with 'S' the record which overlap.
I know that when a table joins itself, the corresponding query could be rewritten using Oracle windows functions.

At the end, the query to rewrite using Oracle Window Functions is the following:

```
  SELECT   NAME,
           D1,
           D2
    FROM   (SELECT   T1.NAME,
                     T1.D1,
                     T1.D2
              FROM   MYDATA T1, MYDATA T2
             WHERE   ( (T1.D1, T1.D2) OVERLAPS (T2.D1, T2.D2))
                     AND T1.NAME <> T2.NAME)
GROUP BY   NAME, D1, D2;
```

Could you me please help to rewrite the query avoiding the self join?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` with `lead` and `lag`:

```
SELECT   D.*,
         CASE
            WHEN LAG (D1) OVER (ORDER BY D1) IS NOT NULL
                 AND (LAG (D1) OVER (ORDER BY D1), LAG (D2) OVER (ORDER BY D1))
                       OVERLAPS (D1, D2)
                 OR LEAD (D1) OVER (ORDER BY D1) IS NOT NULL
                   AND (LEAD (D1) OVER (ORDER BY D1),
                        LEAD (D2) OVER (ORDER BY D1))
                         OVERLAPS (D1, D2)
            THEN
               'S'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END
            OVERLAP
  FROM   MYDATA D;
```

Results:

```
NAME                                               D1        D2        OVERLAP
-------------------------------------------------- --------- --------- -------
A                                                  01-JAN-10 02-MAR-10 N      
B                                                  03-MAR-10 20-MAR-10 S      
C                                                  10-MAR-10 20-SEP-10 S      
D                                                  10-DEC-10 31-DEC-10 N
```

Comment: You're welcome man. It's a good practice always look for analytics solutions, so, glad to help :)